# MS Access Stop Triggering Form_Open event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have written MS Access VBA code.

I have written License code in **Form_Open** Event. License code is available in the registry. During opening the form, the registry value will be compared with the hard coded value inside the code. If both are same, then it will open the form. If both value are not same, It will displayed the message and close the Access application(Application.Quit), **You are not authenticated to use the tool**.

Now I forgot the password in the VBA code.

As soon as open the form, due to both value are mismatched, Modal message box is displayed and I could not open the VBA code at all.

I do not know how to disable the Form_Open event.

Please help me to disable the Form_Open event, and open the VBA code.

Comment: In the Access options you could select _Trust Center_ and _Trust Center Settings_, on the form that opens select _Macro Settings_  and _Disable all macros with notifications_.  Your code shouldn't fire when you open the database then.

Comment: No. I forgot the license password, which I used in VBA code. As soon as I open access file, message box is displayed. I could not open vba editor at all. Based on Andre suggestion, Now I am able to see the vba code. Thanks for all

Answer (score 2):

Hold the Shift key pressed when opening the database to prevent the automatic execution of code or opening of forms.

Then you can open the form in Design view and its code.